# Android Alert Dialog is not showing

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm comparing the strings, if all are equal it has to show a dialog "ALL ARE EQUAL" else another dialog "NOT EQUAL". I want to use only OK button in Alert Dialog. And my code:

```
if(s1.equals("yes") && s2.equals("yes") && s3.equals("yes") && s4.equals("yes"))
        showA();
```

Where the `showA()` method is

```
private void showA() {
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setTitle("Hello!!");
    ab.setMessage("ALL ARE EQUAL");
    ab.setCancelable(false);
    ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = ab.create();

    ad.show();

}
```

Comment: Does it go inside method showA()?

Comment: whats the logcat error?! seems ShowA() nver runs

Comment: Please try with equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals .

Comment: Is there any error in logcat?? Put a break point or put a log inside if or showA() to check whether showA() is ever called or not

Comment: Whats your problem? Please try to give more information on what exactly u want from SO?

Comment: you should write a log trace in the method showA, maybe it method never run

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it doesn't go inside method, I think your string might be "YES" or "Yes".

Why don't you try it as shown below?

```
if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s3.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s4.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    showA();
```

Comment: yea.. My String was 'Yes'. now i changed it.! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Seem your string `s1,s2,s3 &s s4` is in undefined case, better to use [equalsIgnoreCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) like below:

> s1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")

instead

> s1.equals("yes")

Answer (score 2):

```
if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s3.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s4.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))      {
        showA();
} else {
     showB()
}

private void showA() {
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setTitle("Hello!!");
    ab.setMessage("ALL ARE EQUAL");
    ab.setCancelable(false);
    ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = ab.create();

    ad.show();    
}

private void showB() {
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setTitle("Hello!!");
    ab.setMessage("NOT EQUAL");
    ab.setCancelable(false);
    ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = ab.create();

    ad.show();   
}
```

You require something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code works absolutely fine.
Just make sure your strings are equal to `yes` Case-Sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check value of s1,s2,s3,s4 and then compare.

your code is right,.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && s3.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && 

s4.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))      {


       showAlertDialog("All ARE EQUAL");

} else {

     showAlertDialog("All ARE NOT EQUAL");
}



private void showAlertDialog(String msg){

    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setTitle("Hello!!");
    ab.setMessage(msg);
    ab.setCancelable(false);
    ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = ab.create();

    ad.show();    

}
```

Don't put the same code twice, just create a method and pass the parameter which you require.